# Backbone.js fetch after filtering results resetting to original result set

Tags: backbone.js, filtering, backbone.js-collections, backgrid

I'm using Backgrid and Pagination with Backbone and I'm using fetch to filter a collection, which in turn updates the Backgrid table and the Paginations controls.

```
 filterFunction: function (query) {
    _.each(query, function (q) {
      if(List.grid.collection.queryParams.hasOwnProperty(q.key)) {
        var firstValue = List.grid.collection.queryParams[q.key]
        List.grid.collection.queryParams[q.key] = firstValue + ',' + q.value
      } else {
          List.grid.collection.queryParams[q.key] = q.value
          }
       })
      List.grid.collection.fetch(
        {
          'reset': true
     })
  }
```

which works well and once the collection has been filtered I might for example have a collection that is 6 long instead of 60.  My problem arises when I want to unfilter the collection and go back to the original 60 long collection.  I did think I could just call the original listAllFunction - but that function redraws the backgrid and the pagination controls to the page.   I think a much nicer way would be to write some sort of function that overrides the fetch to ask for ALL results.  So something like:

```
List.grid.collection.**fetchALL** (
   {
      'reset' : true,
      'url': // tell it to go and get ALL the results?

   }
)
```

Is this possible?  Or any suggestions on an approach I should take?

Answer (score 0):

As you decided to filter collection using fetch with custom query params, you could reset collection restoring original queryparams before the fetch:

```
List.grid.collection.queryParams = Backbone.PageableCollection.prototype.queryParams;
List.grid.collection.fetch({reset: true});
```